# How to reduce amplitudes array size in Java?

Tags: java, audio, javafx, wav, amplitude

> Searching the web for weeks i came to the following code for
>   calculating the amplitudes of a given `.wav` file in Java . Now
>   the problem is it doesn't scale well at all with big audio files like
>   let's say 30 minutes , the produces array is huge.

To draw it i am using JavaFX [created this repository](https://github.com/goxr3plus/Java-Audio-Wave-Spectrum-API) (ps the code might be different there due to i have not committed some days now).

So :

```
/**                                                                                                                             
 * Get Wav Amplitudes                                                                                                           
 *                                                                                                                              
 * @param file                                                                                                                  
 * @return                                                                                                                      
 * @throws UnsupportedAudioFileException                                                                                        
 * @throws IOException                                                                                                          
 */                                                                                                                             
private int[] getWavAmplitudes(File file) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException , IOException {                                  
    System.out.println("Calculting WAV amplitudes");                                                                            
    int[] amplitudes = null;                                                                                                    

    //Get Audio input stream                                                                                                    
    try (AudioInputStream input = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file)) {                                                      
        AudioFormat baseFormat = input.getFormat();                                                                             

        Encoding encoding = AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_UNSIGNED;                                                                  
        float sampleRate = baseFormat.getSampleRate();                                                                          
        int numChannels = baseFormat.getChannels();                                                                             

        AudioFormat decodedFormat = new AudioFormat(encoding, sampleRate, 16, numChannels, numChannels * 2, sampleRate, false); 
        int available = input.available();                                                                                      
        amplitudes = new int[available];                                                                                        

        //Get the PCM Decoded Audio Input Stream                                                                                
        try (AudioInputStream pcmDecodedInput = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(decodedFormat, input)) {                        
            final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096; //this is actually bytes                                                              
            System.out.println(available);                                                                                      

            //Create a buffer                                                                                                   
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];                                                                              

            //Read all the available data on chunks                                                                             
            int counter = 0;                                                                                                    
            while (pcmDecodedInput.readNBytes(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE) > 0)                                                      
                for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length - 1; i += 2, counter += 2) {                                                  
                    if (counter == available)                                                                                   
                        break;                                                                                                  
                    amplitudes[counter] = ( ( buffer[i + 1] << 8 ) | buffer[i] & 0xff ) << 16;                                  
                    amplitudes[counter] /= 32767;                                                                               
                    amplitudes[counter] *= WAVEFORM_HEIGHT_COEFFICIENT;                                                         
                }                                                                                                               
        } catch (Exception ex) {                                                                                                
            ex.printStackTrace();                                                                                               
        }                                                                                                                       
    } catch (Exception ex) {                                                                                                    
        ex.printStackTrace();                                                                                                   
    }                                                                                                                           

    //System.out.println("Finished Calculting amplitudes");                                                                     
    return amplitudes;                                                                                                          
}
```

And then i process the amplitudes like this :

```
/**                                                                 
 * Process the amplitudes                                           
 *                                                                  
 * @param sourcePcmData                                             
 * @return An array with amplitudes                                 
 */                                                                 
private float[] processAmplitudes(int[] sourcePcmData) {            
    System.out.println("Processing WAV amplitudes");                

    //The width of the resulting waveform panel                     
    int width = waveVisualization.width;                            
    System.out.println("P Width :" + width);                        
    float[] waveData = new float[width];                            
    int samplesPerPixel = sourcePcmData.length / width;             

    //Calculate                                                     
    float nValue;                                                   
    for (int w = 0; w < width; w++) {                               
        //if (isCancelled())                                        
        //  break;                                                  

        //For performance keep it here                              
        int c = w * samplesPerPixel;                                
        nValue = 0.0f;                                              

        //Keep going                                                
        for (int s = 0; s < samplesPerPixel; s++) {                 
            //if (isCancelled())                                    
            //  break;                                              
            nValue += ( Math.abs(sourcePcmData[c + s]) / 65536.0f );
        }                                                           

        //Set WaveData                                              
        waveData[w] = nValue / samplesPerPixel;                     
    }                                                               

    System.out.println("Finished Processing amplitudes");           
    return waveData;                                                
}
```

The output is this :

[image]

Comment: Sample them. Take the average of every X. Or the Max. Or the Min. Or something in between. The user doesn’t need to, and cannot process, the amplitude of every sample - so sample the samples.

Comment: @BoristheSpider A code example please. I am very new to this. Add an answer :)

Comment: Your code is already doing an aggregation by working out how many pixels there are and averaging - just move that code in and make your array the same size as `waveData` is now. I think you understanding your code and altering it yourself will be much more informative than me doing it for you.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Hi , i have added an answer , tried to make it the best i can , no huge arrays saved on memory and the final amplitudes array is very small . Just one thing ( i don't know which the best final size for the amplitudes array should be so i left it 100.000 ) Should i implement also the Min and Max as you said ? Need an opinion here i am lost :)

Comment: Looks like the right approach. For the size of the subarray - why not pass into the method how many samples you need, and the calculate array length from that - like you are going above with the number of pixels? On the min/max, you need to decide what summary statistics to use - you are using the arithmetic mean, if that works for you then keep it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a really good solution , though i am not sure what the final array maximum size should be , after some experiments `100.000` seems a good number.

### All the code is in [this](https://github.com/goxr3plus/Java-Audio-Wave-Spectrum-API) github repository .

So the method **getWavAmplitudes** becomes :

```
/**                                                                                                                                                
 * Get Wav Amplitudes                                                                                                                              
 *                                                                                                                                                 
 * @param file                                                                                                                                     
 * @return                                                                                                                                         
 * @throws UnsupportedAudioFileException                                                                                                           
 * @throws IOException                                                                                                                             
 */                                                                                                                                                
private int[] getWavAmplitudes(File file) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException , IOException {                                                     

    //Get Audio input stream                                                                                                                       
    try (AudioInputStream input = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file)) {                                                                         
        AudioFormat baseFormat = input.getFormat();                                                                                                

        //Encoding                                                                                                                                 
        Encoding encoding = AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_UNSIGNED;                                                                                     
        float sampleRate = baseFormat.getSampleRate();                                                                                             
        int numChannels = baseFormat.getChannels();                                                                                                

        AudioFormat decodedFormat = new AudioFormat(encoding, sampleRate, 16, numChannels, numChannels * 2, sampleRate, false);                    
        int available = input.available();                                                                                                         

        //Get the PCM Decoded Audio Input Stream                                                                                                   
        try (AudioInputStream pcmDecodedInput = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(decodedFormat, input)) {                                           
            final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096; //this is actually bytes                                                                                 

            //Create a buffer                                                                                                                      
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];                                                                                                 

            //Now get the average to a smaller array                                                                                               
            int maximumArrayLength = 100000;                                                                                                       
            int[] finalAmplitudes = new int[maximumArrayLength];                                                                                   
            int samplesPerPixel = available / maximumArrayLength;                                                                                  

            //Variables to calculate finalAmplitudes array                                                                                         
            int currentSampleCounter = 0;                                                                                                          
            int arrayCellPosition = 0;                                                                                                             
            float currentCellValue = 0.0f;                                                                                                         

            //Variables for the loop                                                                                                               
            int arrayCellValue = 0;                                                                                                                

            //Read all the available data on chunks                                                                                                
            while (pcmDecodedInput.readNBytes(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE) > 0)                                                                         
                for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length - 1; i += 2) {                                                                                   

                    //Calculate the value                                                                                                          
                    arrayCellValue = (int) ( ( ( ( ( buffer[i + 1] << 8 ) | buffer[i] & 0xff ) << 16 ) / 32767 ) * WAVEFORM_HEIGHT_COEFFICIENT );  

                    //Every time you him [currentSampleCounter=samplesPerPixel]                                                                    
                    if (currentSampleCounter != samplesPerPixel) {                                                                                 
                        ++currentSampleCounter;                                                                                                    
                        currentCellValue += Math.abs(arrayCellValue);                                                                              
                    } else {                                                                                                                       
                        //Avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException                                                                                     
                        if (arrayCellPosition != maximumArrayLength)                                                                               
                            finalAmplitudes[arrayCellPosition] = finalAmplitudes[arrayCellPosition + 1] = (int) currentCellValue / samplesPerPixel;

                        //Fix the variables                                                                                                        
                        currentSampleCounter = 0;                                                                                                  
                        currentCellValue = 0;                                                                                                      
                        arrayCellPosition += 2;                                                                                                    
                    }                                                                                                                              
                }                                                                                                                                  

            return finalAmplitudes;                                                                                                                
        } catch (Exception ex) {                                                                                                                   
            ex.printStackTrace();                                                                                                                  
        }                                                                                                                                          
    } catch (Exception ex) {                                                                                                                       
        ex.printStackTrace();                                                                                                                      

    }                                                                                                                                              

    //You don't want this to reach here...                                                                                                         
    return new int[1];                                                                                                                             
}
```

Any recommendation and improvements very welcome .

Comment: If you are not handling the exceptions, and then returning nonsense, why catch them at all? Just remove the catch blocks...

Comment: @BoristheSpider I will fix that . Also can i improve it further ( speed  , precision etc ):) ?